Api Platform : returning an array of entity in a processor
I'm working with Api Platform on a processor that enable multi entity post and I want to return an array of entity. After I generate my entities, I store them in an array like this in my process() :
/** @var Code[] $codes*/
$codes = [];

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {   
  // Entity generation and flush    
  $codes[] = $code;
}

return $count == 1 ? $codes[0] : $codes;

And I have this error :

ApiPlatform\Symfony\EventListener\WriteListener::getObjectClass():
Argument #1 ($object) must be of type object, array given, called in
/app/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/EventListener/WriteListener.php
on line 111

Does a solution exist to achieve this, or is this not permitted by API Platform ?
